# Ubuntu Login - Stuck on Login Page

Tags: keyboard, password

I've set up the software on VirtualBox and completed the VM setup and now i am at the login stage. I know the password as i have just set it up, the issue is every time it asks me to put my password in, the keys don't seem to want to work. I mean it doesnt matter what keys i click on the keyboard; unless its 'enter' in the password line, no other character works. Which makes no sense as the keys work for the username login, but when it comes to the password it doesnt want to do anything. How do i fix this?

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; but passwords not showing is a security feature (*anyone behind you cannot tell by watching the screen how many characters you type, which they can if dots; even 3xdots per key appear*). You just type your password & hit enter and you'll login (providing sufficient disk space exists in $HOME & other requirements for certain environments)